# Numerical values of words in Excel cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have text cells in "TEXT" column in an Excel sheet (for example from A2 to A4), and I have a list of words\value where each word has a specific value, this list of words\values are in another sheet or other columns (for example from E2 to F4).

I want to split each string up into individual words and place each word in it's own cell. In a separate range I want to apply each words corresponding value and add each string's values together for a "RESULT" sum of the string.

[image: my trial to solve this - pic2]

It would also be ok if it is possible to compare and return total value in "RESULT" cell without splitting "TEXT" cell into new cells.

[image: an example of the results]

What I've tried doing is place each word from a string in it's own cell using Data > DataTools > Text to Columns. Then using `VLOOKUP` worksheet function to find matching words and applying their corresponding value and then finding the sum of that string range. The code works for smaller data sizes but I'm looking for something more professional and useful (like closer to what the first picture is, compared with the second picture.)

Thanks!

Comment: I post this question with fewer details and less information before, here is a link to the edited version of the same question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40067999/checking-words-value-in-excel-file?noredirect=1#comment67422198_40067999

Answer (score 0):

### Loop Through Words in a Sentence and Compare to Key Words to Find Sum of Key Word Value

---

***This is wildly inefficient code, so depending on the size of your data, run-times could become very long. Place the code found in this answer in a VBA module, and either run it from VBE or assign the macro to a button(shape) on your worksheet.***

---

**The starting data set I used mimics what you provided.**

[image]

**To achieve the result you desire, we can use multiple `For Loops` after constructing `Array()`s to "match" our values and add up a total sum. The ranges defining TEXT and WORD are dynamic, meaning you can add more and more to them and the code will continue to run all the way to the end on it's own.**

```
Sub WordToValue()
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Dim wordArray() As String, word As Variant, myWords As Range
    Dim keyArray() As String, keyWord As Variant
    Dim i As Long, numKey As Long, sumWord As Long
    Dim textRange As Range: Set textRange = ws.Range("A2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Dim keyRange As Range: Set keyRange = ws.Range("D2", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp))

    i = 0
    numKey = 0
    sumWord = 0
    ReDim keyArray(0 To keyRange.Cells.Count)
    For Each myWords In keyRange
        keyArray(i) = myWords.Value
        i = i + 1
    Next myWords

    For Each myWords In textRange
        wordArray = Split(myWords.Value, " ")
        For Each word In wordArray
            For Each keyWord In keyArray
                If LCase(word) = LCase(keyWord) Then
                     numKey = numKey + 1
                     sumWord = sumWord + keyRange.Find(what:=keyWord, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole).Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If
            Next keyWord
        Next word
        ws.Range("B" & myWords.Row).Value = numKey
        ws.Range("C" & myWords.Row).Value = sumWord
        numKey = 0
        sumWord = 0
    Next myWords
End Sub
```

---

**After running this code, the data set will yield the following results:**

[image]

---

Let me know if this achieves what you're asking for.